# Phonegap / jQM app first run has very small text and controls

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova

Below are three pictures showcasing the problem. I will go into more detail right after.

[image: First run, watch the size increase in the next picture]

[image: Everything grew. The header text and size of the controls upon selection]

[image: This is the way it should be, everything is the proper size]

As you can see, something is causing the page to render improperly at first. I can't figure out what it could be. I've reordered the scripts, and the styles. No matter what I do, the first time you run the app the size of everything is very very small, and the only way to correct it is to tap the search bar.

What makes it worse, is that if you look at this in a browser, FireFox or Chrome, before deploying it to the device it renders perfectly. Only until it is on my device does it shrink on first use. And that is the kick, if I hit the home button and come back to my app, it's fine. If I force stop and launch my app, it's small again.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="Scripts/phonegap-1.1.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/common.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="home" data-title="Search">
        <div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
            <h1>
                Search
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="#" method="POST">
                <input id="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" />

                <button type="submit" data-inline="true" data-icon="search" id="searchWikiMedia">
                    Search</button>
            </form>
            <div id="refineSearch">
                <ul data-role="listview">
                </ul>
                <span id="error"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="page" id="result" data-title="Results">
        <div data-position="fixed" data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Search</a>
            <h1>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer">
            <h4>
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: First you should make sure you have a Doctype and run your html through a validator http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this to your between your `<head>` tag's:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
or simply
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Some further reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Thank you! I wish I had asked sooner because it would have saved me about 3 hours of random attempts. I will certainly read that link as well.